# Capture arbitrary string before either '/' or end of string

Tags: ruby, regex

Suppose I have:

```
foo/fhqwhgads
foo/fhqwhgadshgnsdhjsdbkhsdabkfabkveybvf/bar
```

And I want to replace everything that follows 'foo/' up until I either reach '/' or, if '/' is never reached, then up to the end of the line. For the first part I can use a non-capturing group like this:

```
(?<=foo\/).+
```

And that's where I get stuck. I could match to the second '/' like this:

```
(?<=foo\/).+(?=\/)
```

That doesn't help for the first case though. Desired output is:

```
foo/blah
foo/blah/bar
```

I'm using Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/(?<=foo\/)[^\/]+/
```

Comment: This is short and sweet. Thanks!

Comment: Meh, there's no need for the non-capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing @Endophage's answer:

```
def fix_post_foo_portion(string)
  portions = string.split("/")
  index_to_replace = portions.index("foo") + 1
  portions[index_to_replace ] = "blah"
  portions.join("/")
end

strings = %w{foo/fhqwhgads foo/fhqwhgadshgnsdhjsdbkhsdabkfabkveybvf/bar}
strings.each {|string| puts fix_post_foo_portion(string)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a ruby dev but is there some equivalent of php's explode() so you could explode the string, insert a new item at the second array index then implode the parts with / again...  Of course you can match on the first array element if you only want to do the switch in certain cases.

Comment: Ruby supports `split('/')` and `join('/')`.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for the end-of-string anchor -- `$` -- as well as the `/` character should do the trick. You'll also need to make the `.+` non-greedy by changing it to `.+?` since the greedy version will always match right up to the end of the string, given the chance.

```
(?<=foo\/).+?(?=\/|$)
```

Comment: Tried this, but it did not work for me. Treated the / and everything after it as part of the captured group.

Comment: @Ben: In that case you probably need to make the capture non-greedy (by appending a `?`). I'll edit...

Answer (score 0):

```
['foo/fhqwhgads', 'foo/fhqwhgadshgnsdhjsdbkhsdabkfabkveybvf/bar'].each do |s|
  puts s.sub(%r|^(foo/)[^/]+(/.*)?|, '\1blah\2')
end
```

Output:

```
foo/blah
foo/blah/bar
```

I'm too tired to think of a nicer way to do it but I'm sure there is one.